# Checking for port exhaustion with Netstat HttpClientFactory WPF

Tags: port, netstat, httpclientfactory

I want to check that I have properly implemented HttpClientFactory. I have a desktop application that pings my server every 20 seconds. When I open command prompt and run "netstat -ano | findstr {My server IP}" I can see there are always 2 or 3 connections. As time goes on and I continue to check, the ports will slowly change (go up in their port #'s, older ports disappear) but there are never more than 2 or 3 connections. Does this mean that the old ports are being released and I am not at risk for port exhaustion? Thanks.

As mentioned above. I am going to begin selling my application very soon and need to be sure that I am not going to exhaust my client's ports and hinder their network.